# Cause of EXC_BREAKPOINT crash

Tags: c++, macos, debugging

I've got a crash occurring on some users computers in a C++ audiounit component  running inside Logic X.  I can't repeat it locally unfortunately and in the process of trying to work out how it might occur I've got some questions.

Here's the relevant info from the crash dump:

```
Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
```

The questions are:

- What might cause a EXC_BREAKPOINT in the situation I'm looking at.  Is this information from Apple complete and accurate: *"Similar to an Abnormal Exit, this exception is intended to give an attached debugger the chance to interrupt the process at a specific point in its execution. You can trigger this exception from your own code using the __builtin_trap() function. If no debugger is attached, the process is terminated and a crash report is generated."*
- Why would it occur on SharedObject + 200 (see disassembly)
- Is RBX the 'this' pointer at the moment the crash occurs.

The crash occurs here:

```
juce::ValueTree::SharedObject::SharedObject(juce::ValueTree::SharedObject const&) + 200
```

The C++ is as follows:

```
SharedObject (const SharedObject& other)
    : ReferenceCountedObject(),
      type (other.type), properties (other.properties), parent (nullptr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < other.children.size(); ++i)
    {
        SharedObject* const child = new SharedObject (*other.children.getObjectPointerUnchecked(i));
        child->parent = this;
        children.add (child);
    }
}
```

The disassembly:

```
->  0x127167950 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x127167951 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x127167954 <+4>:   pushq  %r15
    0x127167956 <+6>:   pushq  %r14
    0x127167958 <+8>:   pushq  %r13
    0x12716795a <+10>:  pushq  %r12
    0x12716795c <+12>:  pushq  %rbx
    0x12716795d <+13>:  subq   $0x18, %rsp
    0x127167961 <+17>:  movq   %rsi, %r12
    0x127167964 <+20>:  movq   %rdi, %rbx
    0x127167967 <+23>:  leaq   0x589692(%rip), %rax      ; vtable for juce::ReferenceCountedObject + 16
    0x12716796e <+30>:  movq   %rax, (%rbx)
    0x127167971 <+33>:  movl   $0x0, 0x8(%rbx)
    0x127167978 <+40>:  leaq   0x599fe9(%rip), %rax      ; vtable for juce::ValueTree::SharedObject + 16
    0x12716797f <+47>:  movq   %rax, (%rbx)
    0x127167982 <+50>:  leaq   0x10(%rbx), %rdi
    0x127167986 <+54>:  movq   %rdi, -0x30(%rbp)
    0x12716798a <+58>:  leaq   0x10(%r12), %rsi
    0x12716798f <+63>:  callq  0x12711cf70               ; juce::Identifier::Identifier(juce::Identifier const&)
    0x127167994 <+68>:  leaq   0x18(%rbx), %rdi
    0x127167998 <+72>:  movq   %rdi, -0x38(%rbp)
    0x12716799c <+76>:  leaq   0x18(%r12), %rsi
    0x1271679a1 <+81>:  callq  0x12711c7b0               ; juce::NamedValueSet::NamedValueSet(juce::NamedValueSet const&)
    0x1271679a6 <+86>:  movq   $0x0, 0x30(%rbx)
    0x1271679ae <+94>:  movl   $0x0, 0x38(%rbx)
    0x1271679b5 <+101>: movl   $0x0, 0x40(%rbx)
    0x1271679bc <+108>: movq   $0x0, 0x48(%rbx)
    0x1271679c4 <+116>: movl   $0x0, 0x50(%rbx)
    0x1271679cb <+123>: movl   $0x0, 0x58(%rbx)
    0x1271679d2 <+130>: movq   $0x0, 0x60(%rbx)
    0x1271679da <+138>: cmpl   $0x0, 0x40(%r12)
    0x1271679e0 <+144>: jle    0x127167aa2               ; <+338>
    0x1271679e6 <+150>: xorl   %r14d, %r14d
    0x1271679e9 <+153>: nopl   (%rax)
    0x1271679f0 <+160>: movl   $0x68, %edi
    0x1271679f5 <+165>: callq  0x12728c232               ; symbol stub for: operator new(unsigned long)
    0x1271679fa <+170>: movq   %rax, %r13
    0x1271679fd <+173>: movq   0x30(%r12), %rax
    0x127167a02 <+178>: movq   (%rax,%r14,8), %rsi
    0x127167a06 <+182>: movq   %r13, %rdi
    0x127167a09 <+185>: callq  0x127167950               ; <+0>
    0x127167a0e <+190>: movq   %rbx, 0x60(%r13)        // MY NOTES: child->parent = this
    0x127167a12 <+194>: movl   0x38(%rbx), %ecx
    0x127167a15 <+197>: movl   0x40(%rbx), %eax
    0x127167a18 <+200>: cmpl   %eax, %ecx
```

Update 1:
It looks like RIP is suggesting we are in the middle of the 'add' call which is this function, inlined:

```
/** Appends a new object to the end of the array.

    This will increase the new object's reference count.

    @param newObject       the new object to add to the array
    @see set, insert, addIfNotAlreadyThere, addSorted, addArray
*/
ObjectClass* add (ObjectClass* const newObject) noexcept
{
    data.ensureAllocatedSize (numUsed + 1);
    jassert (data.elements != nullptr);
    data.elements [numUsed++] = newObject;

    if (newObject != nullptr)
        newObject->incReferenceCount();

    return newObject;
}
```

Update 2:
At the point of crash register values of relevant registers:

```
this == rbx: 0x00007fe5bc37c950
&other == r12: 0x00007fe5bc348cc0
rax = 0
rcx = 0
```

Comment: Are you hure that `other.children.getObjectPointerUnchecked(i)` does not return `nullptr` before dereferencing it?

Comment: Well, it's a really good question.  But assuming a single thread is operating on the data (which I believe is a valid assumption at this point in construction) for (int i = 0; i < other.children.size(); ++i) _should_ ensure that it's impossible for that to return a nullptr.  There are some callback situations I think which invalidate this assumption but I'm investigating those.  Also - the crash occurs with RIP at +200 which I think means it's in the middle of the 'add' call - I'll post hte source for this.

Comment: Ok - having picked apart which registers are which I think we can say that other.children.getObjectPointerUnchecked(i) is not returning a nullptr.  That's not to say that the pointer doesn't point to some somehow deleted object, but it looks like a good pointer address ....

Comment: Have you attached the debugger to see where it's stopping?  Is the `jassert` in `add` going off, indicating that `data.elements == nullptr`?

Comment: can you post the rest of the code for SharedObject, or at least the default constructor (how childen is initialised) and destructor? Also there could be a problem in your add function (second update), you check if newObject is null AFTER assigning it to data.elements. If you have a loop on data.elements somewhere, you may have some nullptr in there that you don't check. What is the type of data.elements, isn't it where the copy occurs and it crashes?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the problem is that a shared, ref-counted object that should have been placed on the heap was inadvertently allocated on the stack.  If the stack unwinds and is overwritten afterwards, and a reference to the ref-counted object still exists, then random things will happen at unpredictable times when that reference is accessed.  (The proximity in address-space of this and &other also makes me suspect that both are on the stack.)

Comment: Cheers John- that's a good angle.  I'll step though this tomorrow and see if you are onto something.  I have a suspicion that the addresses are close because they were allocated onto the heap at almost the same time though ... but it's worth a good check :)

Comment: Did you figure this out?  If not, it could be useful to get a second reading of the registers at the point of the crash.  Certain things can be randomized at runtime, and how they are changed at runtime can tell you whether you are looking at a stack or heap address.

Comment: I am currently debugging a bug in our software and saw I was getting `EXC_BREAKPOINT` crashes.  I couldn't figure out why I was getting these crashes until after seeing this comment.  This helped me realize that the bug could be a result of an stack/heap overflow since I was getting crashes in random spots every run.  I turned on Xcode's `Address Sanitizer` and toggled on `Detect use of stack after return` and saw red flags in memory length assumptions (i.e. string length and etc).

Answer (score 1):

There may be a few problems in this code:

- like SM mentioned, other.children.getObjectPointerUnchecked(i) could return nullptr
- in `ObjectClass* add (ObjectClass* const newObject) noexcept`, you check if newObject isn't null before calling `incReferenceCount` (which means a null may occur in this method call), but you don't null-check before adding this object during `data.elements [numUsed++] = newObject;`, so you may have a nullptr here, and if you call this array somewhere else without checking, you may have a crash.
- we don't really know the type of data.elements (I assume an array), but there could be a copy operation occuring because of the pointer assignment (if the pointer is converted to object, if data.elements is not an array of pointer or there is some operator overload), there could be a crash here (but it's unlikely)
- there is a circular ref between children and parent, so there may be a problem during object destruction

Comment: Thanks - I'll go through these slowly and make sure I'm not missing something.  Have you any idea why we'd be getting EXC_BREAKPOINT and not EXC_BAD_ACCESS for example though?  Or why it'd report it was crashing on this instruction? 0x127167a15 <+197>: movl   0x40(%rbx), %eax

Comment: EXC_BREAKPOINT seems to be a specific exception to help debugging, if you have a debugger attached. Did you try to attach a debugger and see what was happening during this exception? After re-reading your post, if the crash occurs on the copy constructor (and not inside), you may be passing a nullptr, and dereferencing the ptr (const &) produces the crash.

Comment: There's no debugger attached, that's why it's strange.  This is on a customer machine.  If I could attach a debugger easily it'd be a lot easier to figure out what's going wrong!

Comment: it doesn't mean this would be triggered if a debugger was attached, it's just that, if there's a debugger attached, it would help to debug. It seems this exception is triggered because you try to do something with a null (but most post referred to a nil on Mac or iOS), that's why it is most likely a nullptr somewhere.

Comment: Surely I'd get something like EXC_BAD_ACCESS for a nullptr type problem.  EXC_BREAKPOINT suggests that there's a breakpoint position in a CPU debugging register or possibly an INT3 instruction? Unless I'm missing something...